# How do I get the player's ranking and number of scores submitted in my game which uses Google Play Games?

Tags: google-play-games

I'd like to see if the player is in top 1% of players, so I need to see what rank they are and how many scores have been submitted to the game. How do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rank using methods under [Scores](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores).

Resource representation:

```
{
  "kind": "games#playerLeaderboardScoreListResponse",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "player": players Resource,
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "games#playerLeaderboardScore",
      "leaderboard_id": string,
      "scoreValue": long,
      "scoreString": string,
      "publicRank": {
        "kind": "games#leaderboardScoreRank",
        "rank": long,
        "formattedRank": string,
        "numScores": long,
        "formattedNumScores": string
      },
      "socialRank": {
        "kind": "games#leaderboardScoreRank",
        "rank": long,
        "formattedRank": string,
        "numScores": long,
        "formattedNumScores": string
      },
      "timeSpan": string,
      "writeTimestamp": long,
      "scoreTag": string
    }
  ]
}
```

Use Scores: get method to get high scores, and optionally ranks, in leaderboards for the currently authenticated player.

Take note that this method requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/get#auth)